# Removing gh-pages custom domain

Tags: javascript, dns, github-pages, cname, custom-domain

I have a gh-pages hosted site using a custom domain and now want to remove it. I have removed the gh-pages branch from github, removed the CNAME, removed the homepage in package.json and even removed the @ records pointing to github's ip addresses in the godaddy admin panel but for some reason the site is still up . I am super confused as to why this is still being hosted... is it some kind of cache thing that will expire over time...? Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

- dns provided by godaddy
- is a create react app

Comment: It's probably just cached.

Answer (score 3):

Just cleared my cache in the application tab of dev tools and it seems to have worked, super frustrating though!